# Crash when calling C++ function from C

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, centos7, g++4.8

I have a C++ library function which I am calling from a C function. The call passes in a C data-structure that is accessed by the C++ code. My program crashes in the C++ code when accessing the C data-structure. I've followed all the instructions in [C++ faq](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp) related to mixing C-to-C++.

The crash happens on a centos7 machine. Running the same code in debug mode does not result in a crash. The same code running on Ubuntu (16.04) does not result in a crash. Here's the GDB analysis of the crash.

```
(gdb) frame 5
#5  0x00007fc28e79226e in ngx_http_setup_handler (r=0x2469040)
    at /opt/platform/nginx-noname-module.c:201
201       return ModProcessGetApi(r);
(gdb) p r->unparsed_uri
$1 = {len = 15, data = 0x24572c4 "/__xx/stats/all HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent"}
(gdb) down
#4  0x00007fc28e7945b4 in ModProcessGetApi (r=r@entry=0x2469040)
    at /opt/platform/nginx-body-handler.cc:274
274   ss_rval_t rv = ProcessGetRequest(r, data, &dsize);
(gdb) p r->unparsed_uri
$2 = {len = 38105792, data = 0xf <Address 0xf out of bounds>}
(gdb)
```

As soon as the execution enters the C++ code, the C data structure shows address out of bounds. Here's is the glue code for c-to-c++ functions.

```
#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <nginx.h>
#include <ngx_core.h>
#include <ngx_log.h>
#include <ngx_http.h>

ngx_int_t ModPostRequestBodyHandler(ngx_http_request_t *r);
ngx_int_t ModProcessGetApi(ngx_http_request_t* r);

#if __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I would appreciate it if someone can shed some light on this. Are there any compiler options I need to use when mixing C and C++ code so that the C++ code can access the C data-structure properly? Here's the OS and compiler info:

Centos Version: Crash happens

OS: Centos 7, C++: g++ 4.8.5

Ubuntu Versions: Crash does not happen.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04, C++: g++ 5.4.0

Not sure if it matters but I am running my app in a docker container on both OSes.

Comment: GCC 5.1 itroduced a new `ABI`. Maybe worth looking at this https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html

Comment: @Iharob Thanks taking the time. If I had a choice, I'd do the whole this in c++ like you suggested. Unfortunately, sometimes our hands are tied and we have to make things work in certain environments. That's where I am running into these sort of issues.

Comment: @Galik, Thanks for looking into this. On your GCC 5.1 suggestion, centos7 default GCC version is 4.8.5. I'd like to move to 5.x, but I have to work with the std libraries available on the platform :(

Comment: Calling C++ functions from C works perfectly fine if they're implemented as `extern "C"` and don't throw exceptions. Your problem has nothing to do with C vs C++. You just have a plain old code bug somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Nikos. I thought so too about 'extern "C"' stuff. However, if you look at the GDB session output things are changing as soon I enter the c++ function. BTW, this is in a single-threaded environment. You could still be correct about something else going on here which what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my c++ and C libraries were getting compiled with different #defines, as a result, the C data-structure was different in both the libraries. This results in misaligned access on the c++ side. This problem could have happened in two c libraries as well.

Thanks to all who responded.